# iText 7 - orient PdfWatermarkAnnotation header to portrait when page rotation value is not portrait

Tags: itext7

IText7 - issue with adding header text via PdfWatermarkAnnotation to an existing PDF when the Rotation of the page varies even though all the pages appear to be in portrait when opened up in Acrobat Reader.
80% of the time, the watermark pager header appears where expected.  The other times, it appears as landscape or seascape. 
Does anyone know how to rotate this text when rotation value is 90 (Seascape) or 270 (Landscape)?  [Example Original and PDF With Wrong Pager Header Orientation Step2](https://github.com/nicholsf/itext7HeaderWrongOrientation)

```
     public byte[] Add(string infile, string outFile)
    {
        PdfFont baseFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD, Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName, false);
        Rectangle pageSize;
        string NoOfPagesPadded = string.Empty;
        string PageNoPadded = string.Empty;
        string HdrLeft = string.Empty;
        string HdrRight = string.Empty;
        string AnnotName = "CompanyWatermarkHDR";

        int xLeft = 30;
        int xRight = 110; 
        int xTop = 30;

        float watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth; 
        float watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight = 300; 

        float formXOffset = 0;  
        float formYOffset = -5;  // was zero  set to -5 because dangling letters (e.g. g) were being cut-off
        byte[] outByteFile;
        byte[] inByteFile = null;

        try
        {
            inByteFile = File.ReadAllBytes(infile);
            IRandomAccessSource inSourceFile = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(inByteFile);
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inSourceFile, new ReaderProperties()).SetUnethicalReading(true))
            {
                using (var outMemoryFile = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter pdfWrite = new PdfWriter(outMemoryFile))
                    {
                        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, pdfWrite))
                        {
                            using (Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
                            {
                                int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

                                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                                {
                                    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                                    pageSize = page.GetMediaBox();

                                    watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
                                    float PageWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
                                    float PageHeight = pageSize.GetHeight();
                                    int rotation = page.GetRotation();
                                    Rectangle watermarkTrimmingRectangle = new Rectangle(pageSize.GetLeft() + xLeft, pageSize.GetTop() - xTop, watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth, watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);

                                    PdfWatermarkAnnotation watermark = new PdfWatermarkAnnotation(watermarkTrimmingRectangle);

                                    watermark.SetName(new PdfString(AnnotName));
                                    Rectangle formRectangle = new Rectangle(formXOffset, formYOffset, watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth, watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);

                                    PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(formRectangle);   //Observation: font XObject will be resized to fit inside the watermark rectangle.  If it is larger, your text will be stretched.
                                    PdfCanvas canvasOver = new PdfCanvas(form, pdfDoc);

                                    canvasOver.SetFillColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED);
                                    canvasOver.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10);
                                    canvasOver.SaveState();

                                    string SDSNo = "12345678";
                                    HdrLeft = $"Company SDS {SDSNo}";
                                    HdrLeft = $"PWidth: {PageWidth.ToString()} rotation: {rotation.ToString()}";  //qqtempqq
                                    NoOfPagesPadded = (n.ToString());
                                    PageNoPadded = i.ToString();
                                    HdrRight = $"Page {PageNoPadded} of {NoOfPagesPadded}";
                                    HdrRight = $"PHeight: {PageHeight.ToString()}";  //qqtempqq
                                    canvasOver.BeginText()
                                              .SetColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED, true)
                                              .SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10)
                                              .ShowText(HdrLeft)
                                              .EndText();
                                    canvasOver.BeginText()
                                              .MoveText(formRectangle.GetRight() - xRight, 0)
                                              .SetColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED, true)
                                              .SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10)
                                              .ShowText(HdrRight)                                                  
                                              .EndText();
                                    canvasOver.SaveState();

                                    canvasOver.RestoreState();
                                    canvasOver.Release();

                                    watermark.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(form.GetPdfObject()));
                                    watermark.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

                                    page.AddAnnotation(watermark);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        outByteFile = outMemoryFile.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, outByteFile);

        }    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return inByteFile;
        }
        return outByteFile;
    }
```

Comment: If you are still interested in this question, please share a PDF for which you get the weird result.

Comment: @mkl Good Point. See Original PDF and one with Pager Header in wrong orientation. https://github.com/nicholsf/itext7HeaderWrongOrientation